# Why is it that Owain and Lucina can't get married?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

So I was playing my Fire Emblem Awakening game recently and I finally got Lucina and Owain to get their S-class relationship (yes this is not my first time playing through the game) and I noticed for the first time that down where it lists the Character's supports (ex: Father, Mother, Child, Wife, Husband) they just have companion. Why can they not become Husband and Wife?

Comment: Who was Crom's wife in your game? I seem to recall having the exact same problem, and I think it might be a case of the devs being clever.

Comment: I did Sumia (they are in a cut-scene together). But that does make sense, in Japan it is legal to marry your cousin so I guess instead of removing that they just "covered it up."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in NA version of the game they are listed as companions because they are cousins.

Source:
http://fireemblem.wikia.com/wiki/Lucina
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643003-fire-emblem-awakening/65823321

The strange is that you can do a worse case of incest
http://serenesforest.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=38353

Maybe because of the messed timeline. Well.

Answer (score 0):

Since Lissa and Chrom are siblings, their kids can't get married; they're cousins.